# Getting null as an output from array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

public class a{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("master file.txt"));

    String[] ids = new String[100];


    System.out.println(ids);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    int i = 0;
    ids[i] = sc.next();
    i++;
}
```

I tried to put the data from a file to an array. Im always getting a null as an output. I cant figure out why. This has been very stressing.

Comment: Move the initialization of `i` to `0` before the `while` loop.

Comment: You can't possibly get null as output of this code. The only thing it prints is `ids`, which is initialized to a new array of Strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are printing an array before you filled it with elements.
2. Your counter `i` is reseting to `0` in every iteration of your `while` loop. Although it's not a good idea to use array with fixed number of elements for reading text of unknown length, so use some dynamic array like `ArrayList`.
3. Make sure you have provided the correct path to your `.txt` file.

So your code could look like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("C:/correct/path/to/file/master_file.txt")); 

    List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        while(sc.hasNextLine()) {

           listOfStrings.add(sc.nextLine());

        }

    System.out.println(listOfStrings);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is null because you never assigned anything the array before you try to print it.  I also moved the i outside of the loop so it doesn't get reinitialized each time.  Also since the ids is an array you need to use Arrays.toString(ids) to print it or you just get the object id.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    String[] ids = new String[100];  //array to store lines
    int i = 0;  // line index
    try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("master file.txt"))) { // try resource
        while(sc.hasNextLine()) { // check for next line
            ids[i] = sc.nextLine(); // store line to array index
            i++;  // increment index
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ids));  //print output.
}
```